# My robot.txt file looks fine but doesn't work

Tags: robots.txt

For my website I tried to make a `robot.txt` file so my SEO would be better. After adding the `robot.txt` to my website I expected it to work like it should, but when I checked my SEO with an online site, it showed me it doesn't work.

My `robot.txt` file:

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: When you say something "doesn't work", you need to explain (in natural language) what it is you are trying to do, otherwise we can do little more the check for basic syntax errors in your code. It still may not be doing what you intend it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

You have called the file `robot.txt`, it should be called `robots.txt`.

## Other problems

- You have used the tag `Google`, but GoogleBot uses the tag `Googlebot` [[Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961)].

Comment: Disallow:  and Allow: / are the same thing, you can use either for Googlebot. However, not all bots understand allow directives (google does), so its generally best to keep to robots.txt protocol if its for all bots, which doesn't include allow.

Comment: "You have used the tag `Google`, but GoogleBot uses the tag `GoogleBot`" - Rather curious, I would have expected the shorter identifier "Google" to still catch the Googlebot (it is after all just a shorter pattern). However, testing in [Google's robots.txt tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598) "Google" fails to match the Googlebot UA!?. (Strictly speaking, it's "Googlebot", not "GoogleBot" - but the match is non-case-sensitive anyway.)

Comment: Google​ has a few different bots and user agents, so it needs to be exact so you can block just what you want

Comment: I'm surprised it's not hierarchical, so `google` would cover everything, `google.news` would only affect google news etc.

Comment: The original spec [recommends (but doesn’t require)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18056816/1591669) that bots also recognize substring matches in `User-agent` values.

Comment: @unor Although "Googlebot" is already arguably a _substring_. It seems that, in the case of Google at least, specific user-agent "tokens" are matched _exactly_. I've added [an answer to this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879212/4962819), referenced from your link, with some findings. The [Google Crawlers page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943) is also a good reference as it lists these "tokens".